# C# sql query using count

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am writing a program in visual studio and this is the first time I have used a database and I am having issues with an sql query. I have basically re-written this part of my code down to the basics to try and figure out the issue.

```
private void logIn()
{            
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    string myScalarQuery = "SELECT Count(*) FROM [Table] WHERE (Username = 'donok') AND (Password  = 'donok')";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myScalarQuery, con);
    myCommand.Connection.Open();
    int count = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("count " + count);
}
```

Now when I run this, my message box pops up and tells me the count is 0. If I run the same query on the table instead of through the program, the count is 1 which is what it should be. What is the problem here?

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`. Your query syntax looks sql server

Comment: @Rahul I am using SQL Server

Comment: I don't see an error in your code. Try experimenting with it. What does it return if you drop the where-clause? If you get a count > 0 then there is a problem with the condition.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes good suggestion, I removed the where clause and it still gave me a value of 0.

Comment: I bet the database your code is using and the database you use in management studio are not the same DB. Do you use `AttachDbFilename` in your connection string?